# Threads did not awake with notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following scenario:
Multiple events are coming from a source, with different types each. I need to do something with each event of the same type in sequence, and in parallel if other type. Meaning:

Events from source:
A1, A2, B1, A3, B2, C1

- Listener A, must queue A1, A2 and A3, and work with them in that
  order, in a single thread
- Listener B same as A, in parallel, in a different thread
- Listener C same as B, in parallel, in a different thread

What am i doing to achieve this? in general terms, i have a monitor for each type of event  which i initialize with a new thread and then call to wait(). Every monitor has a queue.

**Monitor.java (implements runnable)**

```
public void run(){
  while(!killed){
    synchronize(this){     
      while(this.stopped){
        wait(); //it waits here when initialized, waiting for the first event
      }

      while(eventQueue.size() > 0){
        //do something with the event
      }

      //i set the flag stopped = true again to wait for the next event
      this.stopped = true;
    }
  }
}
```

When an event arrives, i add it to the queue then notify() the monitor so it breaks the while

```
public void awake(Event event){
  synchronize(this){
    eventQueue.add(event);
    this.stopped = false;
    notify();
  }
}
```

The "killed" flag is used to maintain the thread alive until certain criteria is met. Then, i set the killed flag on true and notify the monitor to end the thread.

My problem is when i run a set of events, sometimes the thread does not awake with the notify(). Sometimes 10 out of 10 events are processed, sometimes, it's 8 of 10 and so on.

I've been looking through the concurrent api searching for some alternative for my problem but i can't find anything good. Could you guys give me any advice on how to confront this problem?

i hope i'm explaining my problem in a good way. If not, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: `this.stopped` needs to be `volatile` because it is used by multiple threads.

Comment: `notify()` or `notifyAll()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The "killed" flag is used to maintain the thread alive until certain criteria is met. Then, i set the killed flag on true and notify the monitor to end the thread.

First off, I would seriously consider switching your code to use a `BlockingQueue` such as the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  You can still use the `killed` flag (which must be `voltile` btw), but by using the `BlockingQueue` all of the signaling is handled for you.  All you do is call `put()` to add things to the queue and `take()` to read from it.  You then don't need to use `synchronized`, `wait`, or `notify`.  You don't need the `stopped` flag at all.  See below.

```
while (!killed) {
   Event event = eventQueue.take();
   ...
```

> My problem is when i run a set of events, sometimes the thread does not awake with the notify(). Sometimes 10 out of 10 events are processed, sometimes, it's 8 of 10 and so on.

In terms of what is going wrong with your current code, I don't see any problems but the devil is in the details.  One thing to remember is that if thread A calls `notify()` and *then* thread B calls `wait()` the notify has been lost.  I think you want to do something like the following:

```
while(!killed){
   Event event;
   synchronized (this) {
       // wait until where is something in the queue
       while(eventQueue.isEmpty()){
           this.wait();
       }
       event = eventQueue.get();
   }
   // work with event
   ...
```

This will only way if the queue is empty and it does not need the `stopped` boolean.

Comment: do i have to do something special when i put the event on the queue? (call notify?) or just by telling eventQueue.put(event) will suppose to awake the thread?

Comment: You need to `put(...)` and then call `notify()` which will wake up a consumer _if_ it is waiting @GoVeM.  If you are using a `BlockingQueue` then you don't need to do the `notify()`.

Comment: i'm actually trying your solution with the `BlockingQueue`, but when i put the event, the thread is still on waiting status.

Comment: You should not be calling wait(), right?  Nor synchronized? All the thread has to do is call take() @GoVeM.

Comment: Thanks Gray, i had to rearrange a couple of things but in the end your solution was perfect. Thank you.